# Replicating Loki Logs to a Central Instance

Tags: linux, logging, loki

I have an embedded device, running (among other things) an InfluxDB and a Loki instance. This device is on the move: usually it is on its own without internet connectivity, but occasionally it has access to its home network. Inside this home network both metrics (InfluxDB) and logs (Loki) shall be transferred/replicated/mirrored onto a central instance.

For InfluxDB this is possible both in real time by [edge data replication](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/write-data/replication/) an retroactively in batches using [a flux query](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/write-data/oss-to-cloud/).

How can I achieve this with Loki/Promtail/LogQL?

1. (soft) real time streaming of all Loki content to a remote instance
2. retroactively mirroring existing logged content to a remote instance